# How to season my tagine if my oven doesn't have setting for the temperature the instructions call for?

Tags: temperature, seasoning-pans

I recently bought a tagine for cooking. I have to season my tagine by heating it in the oven with the temperature below 300 F. My oven works with two settings of 350 and 375F. May I prepare my tagine for use on the stovetop with a diffuser or does it has to be prepared for the initial use in the oven? May I use a higher temperature of 350F? Please help me with your advice.

Comment: Is there a name of a company on the instructions for seasoning?  If so, you might try contacting them.  Does the seasoning call for just heating, or for oiling or other prep before heating?

Comment: What odd oven only has two presets like that?

Comment: Can you give us more information? What material is the tagine made of? What are the instructions for the entire seasoning process?

Answer (score 1):

Ask a good friend, neighbor or nearby relative with a real or proper oven, if you can use theirs for the short period of time required to accomplish this task.

Make them a nice, flavorful dish and carry it over as a Thank-you gift after you are done.